IIS ASP.NET Razor Web Application
Ive created a website using .NET Razor, and when I try and deploy it on my IIS Server(Windows Server 2022) I always get the same error. The folder containing the .dll files is pointed to the correct 'Physical Path' in the website setup, ApplicationPools have been changed to everyone to see if thats the issue, and its not.
I have granted FULL permissions to IIS_IUSRS to ensure there is no conflicts there. But I continue to get the same errors.
Error:
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error       
Config File    \\?\C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\XXXWEBSITENAMEXXX\web.config
Requested URL      http://192.168.0.85:80/
Physical Path      
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WEBSITENAME.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
        <roleManager enabled="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Current runtime installed on my server:
.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.423 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

I have tried to change ApplicationPools to see if thats the issue, I have tried to include NoBindings and stopped the default webpage to see if thats the issue, however the same error persists.

Answer found, I mistakenly didn't have AspNetCoreModule V2 installed, after I installed this, it worked!
